# Why is Telerik JustCode so confused?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, telerik, justcode

I have been using JustCode(latest ver) for about 2 months now, and have started just turning it off most of the time.
The final straw was today when I wasted about an hour trying to find out why I was getting an error(along the lines of no overload with those parameters) when I was sure the code was correct. Finally I turned JC off and the error went away.

Why does it wrongly report errors?
Why does it sometimes disable keys like backspace in a normal code block?
Why does it sometimes color the code in an ASPX page like it is commented out(all green), when it is not(after disabling it VS colors it correctly).

There are lots of other niggly problems like if my mouse is over the word im typing intellisense will not come up etc.

So am I using it wrong or something? It really does look like a promising product from the features videos etc on their site - so I hope the problem is with me :)

Comment: Because it is a bag 'o bugs?  Firing off a rant is healthy for the soul but doesn't make a good question.  Voting to close.

Comment: Well I wasn't actually trying to rant, I was trying to get feedback about if others have the same problems, or if im just an idiot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry to hear you had such problems with JustCode. I suppose you used the Q2 version that was released in July. Some of the problems that you describe – hiding the intellisense, blocking some keys – are problems that others have also reported and were fixed in the Service Pack that was recently released. Please, go ahead and download the latest version. It has other fixes as well than could solve other niggly problems that you may have.

In case you find yourself wondering why some error is showing while you are sure your code is correct – Visual Studio successfully builds the project – try refreshing the code analysis (in **JustCode** menu choose – **Refresh Code Analysis**). That may clear the errors. If the error shows even after that – then position the cursor onto the error and hit **Alt + Enter** (or choose **Fix…** from **JustCode** menu). At the bottom of the popup menu you will find **Report Good Code Red**. This will send over a report for the issue to the team and they’ll contact you with more information on the problem. If you are irritated from the error you can choose **Ignore This Error / Warning** from the same popup menu.

One thing that you can always count on is accurate and prompt response from the team. If you have any problems or suggestions – please, go ahead and write a support ticket or forum post in Telerik’s web site.

Hope this helps.